# Unit Testing a http rest client implemented using boost::beast

Tags: c++, boost, googletest, boost-beast

I have an HTTP REST client implemented using boost::beast.

RESTClient.hpp

```
#pragma once

#include <boost/beast/core.hpp>
#include <boost/beast/http.hpp>
#include <boost/beast/version.hpp>
#include <boost/asio/strand.hpp>
#include <boost/property_tree/json_parser.hpp>
#include <boost/property_tree/ptree.hpp>

namespace beast = boost::beast;
namespace http = beast::http;
namespace net = boost::asio;
using tcp = boost::asio::ip::tcp;


// Performs an HTTP GET and prints the response
class RESTClient : public std::enable_shared_from_this<RESTClient> {

public:
    explicit RESTClient(net::io_context& ioc);

    virtual ~RESTClient();

    virtual void run(char const* host, char const* port, char const* target, int version);

    virtual void onResolve(beast::error_code ec, tcp::resolver::results_type results);

    virtual void onConnect(beast::error_code ec, tcp::resolver::results_type::endpoint_type);

    virtual void onWrite(beast::error_code ec, std::size_t bytes_transferred);

    virtual void onRead(beast::error_code ec, std::size_t bytes_transferred);

private:
    void createGetRequest(char const* host, char const* target, int version);

    void createPostRequest(char const* host, char const* target, int version, char const *body);

    std::string createBody();

    tcp::resolver m_resolver;
    beast::tcp_stream m_stream;
    beast::flat_buffer m_buffer; // (Must persist between reads)
    http::request<http::string_body> m_httpRequest;
    http::response<http::string_body> m_httpResponse;
};
```

RESTClient.cpp

```
#include <boost/beast/core.hpp>
#include <boost/beast/http.hpp>
#include <boost/beast/version.hpp>
#include <boost/asio/strand.hpp>
#include <boost/lexical_cast.hpp>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <iostream>
#include <memory>
#include <string>
#include "RESTClient.hpp"

namespace beast = boost::beast;
namespace http = beast::http;
namespace net = boost::asio;
using tcp = boost::asio::ip::tcp;

void fail(beast::error_code ec, char const* what) {
    std::cerr << what << ": " << ec.message() << "\n";
}


RESTClient::RESTClient(net::io_context& ioc)
    : m_resolver(net::make_strand(ioc)), m_stream(net::make_strand(ioc)) {

}

RESTClient::~RESTClient() = default;


void RESTClient::run(char const* host, char const* port, char const* target, int version) {

    createPostRequest(host, target, version, createBody().c_str());

    m_resolver.async_resolve(host, port, beast::bind_front_handler(
        &RESTClient::onResolve,
        shared_from_this()));
}

void RESTClient::onResolve(beast::error_code ec, tcp::resolver::results_type results) {
    if (ec) {
        return fail(ec, "resolve");
    }

    std::cout << "onResolve ******" << std::endl;
    m_stream.expires_after(std::chrono::seconds(30));

    m_stream.async_connect(results, beast::bind_front_handler(
        &RESTClient::onConnect,
        shared_from_this()));
}

void
RESTClient::onConnect(beast::error_code ec, tcp::resolver::results_type::endpoint_type) {
    if (ec) {
        return fail(ec, "connect");
    }

    std::cout << "onConnect ******" << std::endl;

    m_stream.expires_after(std::chrono::seconds(30));

    http::async_write(m_stream, m_httpRequest,
                      beast::bind_front_handler(
                          &RESTClient::onWrite,
                          shared_from_this()));
}

void
RESTClient::onWrite(beast::error_code ec, std::size_t bytes_transferred) {
    boost::ignore_unused(bytes_transferred);

    if (ec) {
        return fail(ec, "write");
    }

    std::cout << "onWrite ******" << std::endl;

    http::async_read(m_stream, m_buffer, m_httpResponse, beast::bind_front_handler(
        &RESTClient::onRead,
        shared_from_this()));
}

void RESTClient::onRead(beast::error_code ec, std::size_t bytes_transferred) {

    boost::ignore_unused(bytes_transferred);

    if (ec) {
        return fail(ec, "read");
    }

    std::cout << "onRead ******" << std::endl;

    std::cout << m_httpResponse << std::endl;


    m_stream.socket().shutdown(tcp::socket::shutdown_both, ec);

    if (ec && ec != beast::errc::not_connected) {
        return fail(ec, "shutdown");
    }
}

void RESTClient::createGetRequest(char const* host, char const* target, int version) {
    m_httpRequest.version(version);
    m_httpRequest.method(http::verb::get);
    m_httpRequest.target(target);
    m_httpRequest.set(http::field::host, host);
    m_httpRequest.set(http::field::user_agent, BOOST_BEAST_VERSION_STRING);
}


void RESTClient::createPostRequest(char const* host, char const* target, int version, char const* body) {
    m_httpRequest.version(version);
    m_httpRequest.method(http::verb::post);
    m_httpRequest.target(target);
    m_httpRequest.set(http::field::host, host);
    m_httpRequest.set(http::field::user_agent, BOOST_BEAST_VERSION_STRING);
    m_httpRequest.set(http::field::content_length, boost::lexical_cast<std::string>(strlen(body)));
    m_httpRequest.set(http::field::body, body);
    m_httpRequest.prepare_payload();
}


std::string RESTClient::createBody() {
    boost::property_tree::ptree tree;
    boost::property_tree::read_json("test.json",tree);
    std::basic_stringstream<char> jsonStream;
    boost::property_tree::json_parser::write_json(jsonStream, tree, false);
    std::cout << "json stream :" << jsonStream.str() << std::endl;
    return jsonStream.str();
}


int main(int argc, char** argv) {
    // Check command line arguments.
    if (argc != 4 && argc != 5) {
        std::cerr <<
                  "Usage: http-client-async <host> <port> <target> [<HTTP version: 1.0 or 1.1(default)>]\n" <<
                  "Example:\n" <<
                  "    http-client-async www.example.com 80 /\n" <<
                  "    http-client-async www.example.com 80 / 1.0\n";
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }
    auto const host = argv[1];
    auto const port = argv[2];
    auto const target = argv[3];
    int version = argc == 5 && !std::strcmp("1.0", argv[4]) ? 10 : 11;

    // The io_context is required for all I/O
    net::io_context ioc;
    std::cout << "version: " << version << std::endl;

    // Launch the asynchronous operation
    std::make_shared<RESTClient>(ioc)->run(host, port, target, version);

    // Run the I/O service. The call will return when
    // the get operation is complete.
    ioc.run();

    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

I want to unit test this client. I want to be able to POST a specific JSON from this client, and have the mock server reply with another specific JSON. what is the best way to do this. I am using google test

Comment: Hey there. I have a very similar conundrum except I need to unit test a micro-http server implemented with boost, asio, and beast.  By chance did you find a good way to mock out or abstract the asio and beast specific calls so your test didn't have to hit the network?  Or did you go down the path of of having a test server running alongside your client code?  One idea I have is around posting work items into the `io_context` instacne to simulate callbacks into my C++ code.  Would love to hear what you did.